# Android app, receiving data over BLE Module sent by Microcontroller via UART

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller, stm32, uart

I want to create android app, which can connect with bluetooth low energy module and can receive data. In my system microcontroller `stm32f1` send data of measurements over `UART` to the BT LE module.

My question is how to start? I read a lot about `GATT` and `UART` Service, but still don't know how to start. Give me some information please.

Comment: Do you have the services and characteristic structure? We use a Andoid app called "BLE Scanner". This apps shows the structure and you can read and write values in the characteristics.

Comment: Yes, i used this program and got list with UUID adresses, u talked about Custom Service overlap? what is the next step, how to connect characteristics with data send by UART?

Comment: What is you BLE Module, HM-10?

Comment: Bolutek BLE CC41A

Comment: Create a custom service with custom characteristics with read + notify properties, then every time the measurement changes update the characteristics. I think this module uses AT commands to create and update characteristics. The andoid app can subscribe to the characteristics and will recive a notification every time your device updates it.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

- UUIDs of your Service, Characteristic and Descriptor;
- Permissions' Bluetooth Low Energy

The program must:

1. Scan BLE devices
2. Connect a device
3. Set callbacks' BLE

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

> Activity.java

```
// Bluetooth's variables
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
    BluetoothScanCallback bluetoothScanCallback;
    BluetoothGatt gattClient;

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristicID; // To get Value

// UUID's (set yours)
final UUID SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("ab0828b1-198e-4351-b779-901fa0e0371e");
final UUID CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_ID = UUID.fromString("1a220d0a-6b06-4767-8692-243153d94d85");
final UUID DESCRIPTOR_UUID_ID = UUID.fromString("ec6e1003-884b-4a1c-850f-1cfce9cf6567");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Bluetooth
    bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    startScan();
}

 // BLUETOOTH SCAN

private void startScan(){
    Log.i(TAG,"startScan()");
    bluetoothScanCallback = new BluetoothScanCallback();
    bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(bluetoothScanCallback);
}

// BLUETOOTH CONNECTION
private void connectDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (device == null) Log.i(TAG,"Device is null");
    GattClientCallback gattClientCallback = new GattClientCallback();
    gattClient = device.connectGatt(this,false,gattClientCallback);
}

// BLE Scan Callbacks
private class BluetoothScanCallback extends ScanCallback {

    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onScanResult");
        if (result.getDevice().getName() != null){
            if (result.getDevice().getName().equals(YOUR_DEVICE_NAME)) {
                // When find your device, connect.
                connectDevice(result.getDevice());
                bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(bluetoothScanCallback); // stop scan
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBathScanResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ErrorCode: " + errorCode);
    }            
}

// Bluetooth GATT Client Callback
private class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onConnectionStateChange");

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange GATT FAILURE");
            return;
        } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange != GATT_SUCCESS");
            return;
        }

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange CONNECTED");
            gatt.discoverServices();
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange DISCONNECTED");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        Log.i(TAG,"onServicesDiscovered");
        if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) return;

        // Reference your UUIDs
        characteristicID = gatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_ID);
        gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicID,true);

        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristicID.getDescriptor(DESCRIPTOR_UUID_ID);
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCharacteristicRead");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCharacteristicWrite");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCharacteristicChanged");
        // Here you can read the characteristc's value
        // new String(characteristic.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorRead(gatt, descriptor, status);
        Log.i(TAG,"onDescriptorRead");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
        super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
        Log.i(TAG,"onDescriptorWrite");
    }
}
```

**Libs:**

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
```

**Notes:**

- The UUIDs must be same seted on the module.
- In your program you must have two callbacks: ScanCallback and GattCallback. Scan callback is to manage the scan results and the GattCallback you can manage the data input/output.
- This code the basic to show how use BLE on Android, works fine for me.
- You can generate UUID here: [https://www.uuidgenerator.net/](http://UUID%20Generator)

Comment: please send me a list of libs which you import and let me check it is working or not.

Comment: for me descriptor is 0x2902, can i just copy it ino DESCRIPTOR_UUID_ID line?

Comment: Of course. But you must use the fulll UUID in 128bit format String. I don't remember which is, but you can see in the `BLE Scanner`

Comment: I think that is: `00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`. To UUID 0x2902.